# Display database rows in a table in the view file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Basically, I'm having trouble with interpreting some data in my View file, that is being sent over from the controller.

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I am using Razor which I believe is part of Web Pages.

So below I have some code that I am trying to put into a table in my view file, it's basically just all in this case the requests from my database. At the moment this would currently get 12 rows of data and I would like to manage this data into a table.

```
var requests = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString").Query("SELECT * FROM Requests");
                model.requests = from o in requests
                             select new { RequestId = o.RequestId, UserId = o.UserId, ModuleId = o.ModuleId, no_rooms = o.no_rooms, Parks = o.Parks, Rooms = o.Rooms, Weeks = o.Weeks, Day = o.Day, Semester = o.Semester, StartTime = o.StartTime, EndTime = o.EndTime, Length = o.Length, Students = o.Students, Type = o.Type, Priority = o.Priority, Comments = o.Comments, Facilities = o.Facilities, Status = o.Status, Round = o.Round, DateSubmitted = o.DateSubmitted, Year = o.Year };
```

Now in my view file, I'm basically trying to do something like this

```
@foreach (var request in Model.requests)
{
  <tr>
    @request.RequestId 
  </tr>
}
```

Now if I do this, I get the following build error:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'RequestId'
```

Now, the model definition for requests is the following:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> requests { get; set; }
```

Just a note, that if i only did `@request` rather than `@request.RequestId` i get the following output for each row:

```
{ RequestId = 1, UserId = 1, ModuleId = 1, no_rooms = 3, Parks = Central,Central,Central, Rooms = 1,2,3, Weeks = 1, Day = 1, Semester = 1, StartTime = 09:00, EndTime = 13:00, Length = 4, Students = 179, Type = Booking, Priority = P, Comments = , Facilities = 1, Status = 1, Round = 1, DateSubmitted = 11/03/2015 21:59:22, Year = 2015/2016 }
```

How can I make it so I can output the rows into a table in my view file?

Comment: Do you have a @model declaration in your view? If so, then you may need to look at explicitly iterating the objects in your collection with a for loop syntax rather than the foreach syntax...

Comment: @model build_01.Models.Timetabler.TimetablerHome

Comment: It outputs @request just fine, I get the error when I try and target anything, such as request.RequestId

Comment: I attempted looping through with a for loop then doing something like request[i].RequestId but it tells me that I can't do [] after the request or in this case it would be Mode.request[i].RequestId but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

if "requests" is your Model that you are passing to view, then your view should look like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<ApplicationName.Models.Request>

// table
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Request ID</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var request in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@request.RequestId</td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

If you don't have a strongly typed model for Requests in your project, it might be worthwhile to create one.

```
public class Request
{
  public int RequestId { get; set; }
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public int ModuleId { get; set; }
  public int no_rooms { get; set; }
  public string Parks { get; set; }
  etc...
}
```

Comment: Okay but how do I alter my controller stuff to set it with the database values?

Comment: As there will be multiple rows being passed

Comment: what is "model" in your controller action?  You have "model.requests", suggesting that "model" is a class object, and "requests" is a property of that class.

Comment: model calls a model of general declarations and public IEnumerable<dynamic> requests { get; set; } is one of them.

Comment: Dynamic, in this context, ends up being resolved as Object, which may be why you're having issues resolving properties of your model properly (eg xxx is  not a property of type Object). Is there a particular reason you're using dynamic in this way, rather than the model class itself?

Comment: I'm just new to this and didn't realise this was a way to do it :)

Comment: Understand! It's all a bit Greek when your first starting no matter what the process :) I'd suggest you take a look at the model directive @Eckert illustrated above. Look at the model class for your data, and see what happens if you apply his notion to your view.